# Node replicas are not getting updated data from leader (SOLR)

Tags: solr

I'm updating values in xml documents in leader but replicas are not updated.
How to force replicas to refresh all documents?

Answer (score 0):

You have to commit after updating or indexing.
like

`http://node2:8983/solr/update?commit=true'`